# Is there any way to store KML file in Core data

Tags: ios, core-data

Is there any way to store KML file in Core data because i have to send the KML file with some parameters and i have to save KML file along with these Parameters is there any way to store the KML file in Core Data.
 Thanks in Advance

Comment: KML is just text. Store it like any other text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possible solutions:

1) Save the files to the file system in the documents directory. Store the relative path in core data.  Make sure to store the relative path not the absolute path, as the absolute path may change.  This allows you to store meta data about each file but keep the saving and reading of those file separate from core data

2) Store the files in core data as binary data.  In your core data model there is an option to set a property as `Store in External Record File` - you should set it.  Also if you don't want to load the file into memory every time you access other meta data that is stored in the Entity then should should store the binary data in a separate entity with a relation to the metadata entity

3) You can also discard the KML and store all the information in it in core data with custom Entities and objects. If you want to search or sort KML files based on the data inside of them then you will have to parse them and store at least some of its information in core-data.  (Perhaps that is what you intended when you said "some parameters"?).  For some application it might be the best approach to parse the entire file and put ALL of the data into core data and the discard the files.  It depends on your application.

I would recommend approach 1.

Comment: Thanks Sir u used First but with little modification. After send  to server i have to delete the KML file so that App size not increased. So i compare the name with both core data array and Document Directory array but Why the way thanks for your help SIr.